# Computer motherboard power stuck at on and off cycle

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, desktop, desktop-computer

I can not get my computer power on.
When I hit the power switch button, the motherboard start to work and immediately shutdown

> The PC will **work** for several seconds - fans start spinning and LED's light up, and then turn off. Shortly after, fans start spinning and LED light up again. This cycle continues to infinity. The fan of power supply and CPU are all at the same pace.

I tried to reach the **power switch** pins manually(trigger it by touching with screwdriver) still the same result.

Comment: Any beep codes? Is the CPU seated correctly, with no bent pins? Have you tried resetting the CMOS?

Comment: Have you done any hardware manipulation before this started?

Comment: Sorry, I just start to troubleshoot. And I do not have any clue, so I rush to ask some help here. To answer both of your question, none of the above.                                                                                                                      I just reinstall the fan of cpu and the problem solved. Apparently I should try basic step first. I would appreciate some analysis of the cause this problem just for a better discussion.

Comment: Without the CPU fan the CPU will get very hot and shutdown to prevent damage.

Comment: I do not think the fan of cpu is the problem. The fan will start to spin when the power switch were triggered. And I have tested without the fan the motherboard will still power on for about a minute and then shutdown.